# Custom notification being contracted

Tags: android, notifications

I am creating a custom notification using remoteviews. It works great, but if another notifications arrive then my custom notification gets contracted.

Is there any way to always have it expanded?

I use this code:

```
 Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MyContext);
 builder.setTicker("My ticker"); 
 ... other builder values ...     

 RemoteViews oRemoteViews = new RemoteViews(Contexto.getPackageName(), R.layout.my_notification_layout);
 oRemoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.myIcon, R.drawable.myicon); 
 oRemoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text1, "Other text here");
 ... other views values ...

 Notification oNotification = builder.build();
 oNotification.bigContentView = oRemoteViews;
 NotificationManager oNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) Contexto.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 oNotificationManager.notify("xxxxx", NOTIF_ID, oNotification);
```

Comment: No. There isn't. That's how the system works. Only 1 notification can be expanded at a time and you can't force it to be yours.

Comment: Oh I see. It is a pitty because there is a lot of free space anyway even for 2 expanded notifications

Comment: The user can manually re-expand your notification if he wants to. Using two fingers and "pushing" it.

Comment: Thanks! But the idea is to have it displayed entirely